# duplicate values when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join 3 tables to generate a page that displays the member's name, their websites, and their music albums.

The problem I am having is that I am getting duplicate data.

For example, the rows I get in return repeat the album titles twice; and the website values are repeated thrice.

Below is how my tables look like:

```
member_profiles

id   |   alias_name
2    |  Lazy Turtle
3    |    Ms. Cat

member_websites

id   |   member_id   |         site_url         |   site_title
57   |       3       |     http://example.com   |   My Site
58   |       3       |   http://fakesite.com    |   Cool Site
59   |       2       |  http://anotherfake.com  |  Turtlez Site

music_albums

id   |   member_id   |        album_title
5    |       3       |      Cats Rock N Roll
6    |       2       |        My Slowness
7    |       3       |  Meow Pt. II (The Remixes)
8    |       3       |  The Worst Songs I've Made
```

How can I remedy this without having to separate my queries and possibly compromising the performance?
My sql query looks something like this:

```
SELECT mp.name, mw.site_url, mw.site_title, ma.album_title
FROM member_profiles mp
LEFT JOIN member_websites mw ON mw.member_id = mp.id
LEFT JOIN music_albums ma ON ma.member_id = mp.id
WHERE mp.id = 3
```

Comment: For member id = 3, there are duplicate entries in member_websites and music_albums. It is reasonable to have multiple rows in the output for this

Comment: what is your expected output for idd = 3?

Comment: edited my reply. but basically, what's happening is that with this query, i get 6 rows as a result. and the site_urls, site_titles, and album_titles all repeat themselves.. meaning when i loop through the rows, the values will repeat... though i guess i could just check in php if ive already outputted the value and not output it anymore if thats the case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some GROUP_COCAT().

```
SELECT mp.name, GROUP_CONCAT(mw.site_url), GROUP_CONCAT(mw.site_title), GROUP_CONCAT(ma.album_title)
FROM member_profiles mp
LEFT JOIN member_websites mw ON mw.member_id = mp.id
LEFT JOIN music_albums ma ON ma.member_id = mp.id
WHERE mp.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using join with main table and other table has multiple websites and multiple music albums, you can use sub queries for you answer.

```
SELECT mp.name,
 ( select group_concat(mw.site_url) from member_websites mw where mw.member_id = mp.id) as websites ,
 (select group_concat(ma.album_title) from music_albums ma where ma.member_id = mp.id) as albums
FROM member_profiles mp
WHERE mp.id = 3
```

Comment: hey, i guess sub queries could work.. although i am concerned about how they might slow down the performance.. maybe i am better off just looping through the rows in PHP, and storing the values for site_url, site_title and album_title in their own arrays.. i would check if the value already exists in the array before pushing it..

Comment: Your process is more slow then using sub queries, you are going to fire queries three times i think that is not good idea.

Comment: no, i mean once ive retrieved the result object, i will loop through the result object and get the site_url, site_title, and album_title.. i will push them in their own arrays.. but only if the current value doesnt exist yet in that specific array :)

Comment: you have 10 member and each member has 10 websites and 10 albums, you need only 10 member but not intensional you are fetching 100 rows from database,  And you apply messy loop over the values to get only 10, and other hand if you want to apply pagination so how can do that i am sure pagination will not work with your approach.

Comment: Sorry post comment as answer by mistake